# react-native image animation with flex properties

Tags: react-native

I have a large image on center of a page.
There are textboxes below the image. Once the user clicks on a textbox I want the image to move to top right corner of the page.

Here is the constructor of the class -

```
         constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            const {theme} = props;
            this.theme = theme;

    //****Initial state of the image (centered aligned on the parent container)
            this.state = {
              imgDimensions: {height: 93, width: 206, alignSelf: 'center'},
              keyboardOpen: false,
            };
    //********

            this.moveIcon = this.moveIcon.bind(this);
            this.unMoveIcon = this.unMoveIcon.bind(this);

            this._keyboardDidShow = this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this);
            this._keyboardDidHide = this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this);

            this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
          }
```

Now I am calling this method on textbox click to resize the image and move to top-right corner -

```
  moveIcon() {
    this.setState({
      imgDimensions: {
        height: 39,
        width: 87,
        alignSelf: 'flex-end',
        top: getStatusBarHeight(),
        //marginTop: 20,
        position: 'absolute',
      },
    });
```

Can this movement from flex 'center' to 'flex-end' be animated?
Please let me know if I can provide more information.

Here is the Image code -

```
        <Animated.Image
          style={{
            ...this.state.imgDimensions,

          }}
          source={require('../../assets/images/logo_final.png')}
          resizeMode="contain"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this package
[react-native-animatable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animatable)
to Install

```
npm install react-native-animatable --save
```